# Linker issues while cross compiling for ARM(arm6ec) platform

Tags: c++, arm, windows-runtime, linker-errors

I am trying to do cross compile for arm64EC platform. Where the linker complains about this issue for `debug` flavor builds. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478055/lnk2013-error-fixup-overflow) useful but it didn't help.

```
libcmtd.lib(callhelpers_fo.obj) : error LNK2013: BRANCH26 fixup overflow.  Target '#__os_arm64x_direct_check_icall_cfg' is out of range
libcmtd.lib(callhelpers_fo.obj) : error LNK2013: BRANCH26 fixup overflow.  Target '{thunk}#__os_arm64x_direct_check_icall_cfg' is out of range
libcmtd.lib(callhelpers_fo.obj) : error LNK2013: BRANCH26 fixup overflow.  Target '#__os_arm64x_direct_check_icall' is out of range
libcmtd.lib(callhelpers_fo.obj) : error LNK2013: BRANCH26 fixup overflow.  Target '{thunk}#__os_arm64x_direct_check_icall' is out of range
libcmtd.lib(callhelpers_fo.obj) : error LNK2013: BRANCH26 fixup overflow.  Target '#__os_arm64x_direct_check_call' is out of range
libcmtd.lib(callhelpers_fo.obj) : error LNK2013: BRANCH26 fixup overflow.  Target '{thunk}#__os_arm64x_direct_check_call' is out of range
LINK : fatal error LNK1165: link failed because of fixup errors
```

I try to link in non-incremental mode by passing `/INCREMENTAL:NO` to the linker. But no luck. I want to understand what is the reason behind this issue? Any reference would really help.